# I mentioned a travel on Most recent travels before making the travel because my appointment date was after the travel. Is that okay?

Tags: visas, uk

I had a work visa to the UK for which I had to travel on Jan 10, 2024 to Jan 23, 2024. It is valid only for one month. On Jan 1st I then applied for a standard visit visa to travel in March 2024 to be with my in-laws and wife. On most recent travels to UK, I added the January travel because my visa appointment date was for January 29th. Will it be a problem that I added this travel before travelling?